# Microsoft CRM Custom Workflow - Key Not Found

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to write a custom workflow for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 as a training exercise. The code I have used is below, which works fine for a standard plugin but, when running as part of a custom workflow gives me a key not present in dictionary error. Can anyone spot any reason for this? I've checked the entity and field names which are all correct.

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;

using System.Diagnostics;


namespace TestWflow
{

    public class SampleCustomActivity : CodeActivity
    {


        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
        {
            //Activity code

            // Get the context service.
            IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();

            // Use the context service to create an instance of IOrganizationService.
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);

            if (context.Depth == 1)
            {

                Entity targetCont = null;
                targetCont = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
                Guid contID = targetCont.Id;
                ColumnSet contCols = new ColumnSet("jobtitle");

                targetCont = service.Retrieve("contact", contID, contCols);

                targetCont.Attributes["jobtitle"] = "test jobtitle here";
                service.Update(targetCont);


            }



        }



    }


}
```

Comment: How is the workflow firing?

Comment: I am triggering it manually at the minute.

Comment: Try new ColumnSet(true)

Comment: @Bvrce - Thank you, but it's still doing the same if I try that

Comment: Please post the exception.

Comment: @Bvrce The error given is:  Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): TestWflow.SampleCustomActivity: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your code is blowing up on: 
    targetCont = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

My plugin code has always been a little different from my workflow code in how it gets data.

So try to add to your code:

context.PrimaryEntityId

In the end your code should look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;

using System.Diagnostics;


namespace TestWflow
{

    public class SampleCustomActivity : CodeActivity
    {
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
        {
            //Activity code

            // Get the context service.
            IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>   ();
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();

            // Use the context service to create an instance of IOrganizationService.
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);

            if (context.Depth == 1)
            {
                Guid contID = context.PrimaryEntityId;
                ColumnSet contCols = new ColumnSet("jobtitle");

                var entity = service.Retrieve("contact", contID, contCols);

                entity.Attributes["jobtitle"] = "test jobtitle here";
                service.Update(entity);


            }



        }



    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but when I try and register the plugin I get the following error:

Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: The property Target is of type EntityReference but doesn't contain the ReferenceTarget attribute

Comment: yeah.  you would have to change your workflow to pass in an entity reference as a parameter.  Since all you need is the guid Id of the target entity it is not really necessary to invest the time to add that parameter, since you can grab it from the workflow context.  I have changed my code above accordingly.

Comment: ps:  after you get this working, you might invest a bit of time learning how to register, configure and code up workflow assemblies that use parameters.